# Fitting logistic curve

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to use FindFit to the logistic population model which I define as

```
model2 = L/(1 + (L/P0 - 1) e^(-kt))
```

on the data

```
data = {19, 39, 46, 73, 92, 109, 137, 160, 177, 202, 230, 257, 299, 342, 
384, 419, 464, 511, 553, 597, 646, 684, 734, 779, 814, 851, 895, 929, 
962, 988, 1011, 1040, 1069, 1110, 1141, 1165, 1195, 1212, 1226, 1247, 
1269, 1288, 1303, 1318, 1332, 1341, 1354, 1367}
```

but I get this [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFbI5.png). I am using FindFit as follows

```
fit = FindFit[data, model2, {P0, L, k}, t]
```

The data is supposed to represent population size at different days, so 19 corresponds to population at day 1, 39 is population at day 2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use capital E as in `E^(-k t)`

See https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/E.html